# Adding an image to my UIViewController

Tags: iphone, image, uiviewcontroller

just a quick question here.

How can I add an image to my UIViewController. Currently, my view controller has a couple labels and a couple buttons, but I have a file line.jpg that I'd like to add to this view controller as well. And I'd like to add it at a specific location (namely, at the center of the screen). How could I (meaning, what is the code?) initialize some object (that encapsulates my image) and then add it to the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIImageView` for that.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html